# Yii STAT relation with conditional statement

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am trying to creating a STAT relation for a model that sums up the contents of a column provided that another column matches my conditional statement. In my particular case, I need to get the sum of all the file sizes of the pictures that a user has uploaded.

Code:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'pictureSpaceUsed'=>array(self::STAT, 'Picture', 'user_id', 'select' => 'SUM(size)','condition' => 'user_id=' . $this->id),
        ),
    }
}
```

Problem is that Yii complains that it can't access the id of the model. `$this->id` doesn't seem to be working inside the relations function... It works if I replace `$this->id` with a number though, but that wouldn't be dynamic anymore.

Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to insert that condition? It looks like you already state the condition when you say:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord {
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'pictureSpaceUsed'=>array(self::STAT, 'Picture', 'user_id', 'select' => 'SUM(size)'),
    ),
}
```

}

It will find the relation based on user_id

Comment: I want to check if the user_id matches the user model's id. The table contains records that belong to many users. I only want to sum up the rows that relate to a SPECIFIC user.